# Installing OpenSSL (or Node.JS) on RHEL 5

Tags: rhel5, openssl, node.js

I have to install Node.JS on a customer’s server which runs RedHat Enterprise Linux 5 (5.3, afaik). I’m an experienced Debian and Gentoo admin, but have not worked with RedHat systems for about 10 years.

As far as I can see, there’s no official Node.JS package; therefore I’d try building from source. That’s not a problem for me, however, I need to build it with OpenSSL support, which means I need OpenSSL development libraries installed (something like the `libssl-dev` package on Debian systems). Node.JS’s `./configure` cannot find it, so I guess it’s not installed by default. For OpenSSL, I guess, a package should exist.

Now:

How do I install the OpenSSL dev package? Or do I have to build it from source, too? (I could, but I guess using a package is easier.) Please note that I don’t know what the preferred package manager on RHEL is (`yum`, I guess?) or how to use it. Telling me the exact commands would therefore be nice.

Or, is there a Node.JS package which I should install instead?

The server in question is managed by quite security-aware admins, so installing an RPM found in a forum or the like is not an option. (And no, they won’t install it for me, but yes, they are willing to give me root to do it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `openssl-devel`. Use `yum` to install it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Fedora or EPEL package for `node.js` at this point, but one is under review. See: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=634911

You could use this (and [dependencies](http://v3.sk/~lkundrak/blog/entries/nodejs.html)) as a basis for building RPMs for your system.

Answer (score 0):

`#yum install openssl-devel` install and try :)

Answer (score 0):

This is surely too late to help the original poster, but for anyone stumbling upon this topic: I've just stumbled upon a very good unofficial set of node RPMs:

http://nodejs.tchol.org/